# MS documentation of enumerations, like ControlMode

Tags: 2013, list-view, edit-form

I am having trouble finding the different values for certain properties. For example I'm trying to track down what `ControlMode:4` is.

I found [SPControlMode enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spcontrolmode.aspx) but there is no enumeration to say what the values are is it zero or 1 based? I think it is zero based which means New is 3, but in that case there is no 4.

So does anybody know what ControlMode of 4 is?

Also why ais the msdn documentation so lousy on this. For example the [Workflow status documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.workflowstatus.aspx) doesn't show the actual values either.

Does anybody have a good resource for finding the actual values?

Answer (score 1):

It's defined in the `clienttemplates.js` file.

```
SPClientTemplates.ClientControlMode = {
        Invalid: 0,
        DisplayForm: 1,
        EditForm: 2,
        NewForm: 3,
        View: 4
    };
```

---

Edit for Workflow statuses:

If you look into the [MS-SPWCSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh641700(v=office.12).aspx) docs you'll notice each individual status has a value. For example:

```
3.1.5.12.1.4 Canceling
SharePoint
Value: 3
```

For js, it's defined in the `SP.Workflow.Services.js` file:

```
SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowStatus.prototype = {
    notStarted: 0, 
    started: 1, 
    suspended: 2, 
    canceling: 3, 
    canceled: 4, 
    terminated: 5, 
    completed: 6, 
    notSpecified: 7, 
    invalid: 8
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where the Workflow statuses are defined as well?